# using import breaks extending internal modules

Tags: typescript

Here is my scenario. I'm defining a module "mine" across multiple files. I use reference path includes to include the files. However, when I use import in one of the files, the names inside internal modules don't resolve anymore. I need to explicity reference the module name..

**a.ts:**

```
module mine {
    export class A {
    }
}
```

**e.ts:** (I don't own this, typically downloaded from web)

```
declare module "ext" {
    export var xyz;
};
```

**b.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="a.ts" />
/// <reference path="e.ts" />
import ext = module("ext");
module mine {
    export class B extends A {
    }
}
```

When I compile b.ts using 'tsc --target ES5 b.ts', I get the following error.

```
E:/Prem/src/redsnake/try/b.ts(5,27): Expected type
E:/Prem/src/redsnake/try/b.ts(5,27): Base type must be interface or class
```

However, if I remove the import statement in b.ts, everything works fine. My question is, how do I extend a internal module while importing another external module.

I added e.ts for the explanation, but technically e.ts can come from external typescript definition files I get through tsd or download from web. The issue I'm particulary hitting is with node.js assert module.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the TypeScript compiler -- your code is (or at least ought to be) fine. The issue just got fixed in the 0.9 branch.